# Security with LinkedIn email verification

Tags: single-sign-on, linkedin-api

As I know, when we register new LinkedIn account, we don't need to verify the email before using it.

There is a feature in our platform which allows users log in with LinkedIn account.

There is user A with email: userA@domain.com. User A, has already registered my platform with that email.

Another user register a new LinkedIn account with email userA@domain.com (this email hasn't been used in LinkedIn and hasn't verified by email). Then he goes to our platform and logged by his LinkedIn email userA@domain.com. He then can see all information of user A.

What should I do to prevent this case?

Thanks in advance

Comment: So you need to know how to identify such unconfirmed linked in accounts?

Answer (score 0):

Block the login attempt, warn the user, flag the account as pending verification, and send an email with a verification code. If they're truly the same user, migrate any data you store for that account to the LinkedIn provider.

Also, think about what you communicate in that verification email. If user #1 was a fake, the login failure and verification email will be the first indication to user #2 that somebody else was using their email address.

You could get more complex -- give them one link to verify and migrate the account, or another link to indicate user #1 is *not* them, in which case you may want to freeze or investigate user #1 further (maybe look at IP addresses, etc).

Authentication is surprisingly complex!